# How does Android perform callbacks on my thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

I see similar questions, but the answers vary and are not unified.

Consider a MediaPlayer and a registered listener (e.g. for completed
playback, or onPrepared, etc.). I tested it and the callback is
executed on the same thread as the one that started the playback.
Since my app is a game, this thread is *not* the UI thread, it's the
game's thread (without any handler, by the way).

Are there any guarantees about when it will be called? My game thread
is constantly running, so I can't really imagine *how* and with what
restrictions (if any) my callback gets called by the system. My game
thread is constantly working so the callback must get called in the
middle of an operation (?) -- but then I don't get it.

Comment: That is not possible.  If execution of callback code happens 'asynchronously', then the callback must have been called by another thread. Threads cannot be called, they can only be signaled.  IF a thread wishes to run some 'callback' code upon a signal, it must be waiting on the signal, eg. Windows APC calls - a thread must be waiting on its message queue to retrieve the callback queued to it so that it can execute it with its own context

Comment: Checking the Android source, it seems that the MediaPlayer has a looper and an associated handler. (That is exactly an implementation of what you describe, i.e. a message queue.) But I don't know when my game thread processes messages i.e. when does it call the handleMessage in it (because I don't explicitly do it, the Android system does it instead, but I wonder *when*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after more tests, and after putting the thread name logging to the correct places.

If your thread (which created the MediaPlayer) is not a Looper, then Android cannot send messages to it obviously. So it will call these callbacks from your UI thread (via a message queue mechanism, as Martin James told it as well). This was confirmed by my tests, and it is conceptually correct as well (as it fits into the Looper concept of the Android architecture).